# sql query: how to perform multiple count comparison inside one table

Tags: mysql, sql

say i have a table like this:

Buys(cid: integer, pid: integer, day date)

Each row in this table represents a single purchase, an event when customer with id cid bought product with id pid at the date and time specified by day.

I want to find all the cids of customers who buy each product the same number of times. For example, if a customer has 3 purchases of item 101, that customer must also have 3 purchases of any other item she bought.

Comment: should the purchase be on the same day?

Comment: no, the date doesn't matter

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Check the Stack Overflow's [help on asking questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) first, please. Focus on [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask), [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `MOD` function to see if the remainder of the division of total rows per cid and the distinct pid's is 0.

```
select cid
from buys
group by cid
having MOD(count(*),count(distinct pid)) = 0
```